# Docker from python

Tags: python, docker

Please be gentle, I am new to docker.

I'm trying to run a docker container from within Python but am running into some trouble due to environment variables not being set.

For example I run

```
import os
os.popen('docker-machine start default').read()
os.popen('eval "$(docker-machine env default)"').read()
```

which will start the machine but does not set the environment variables and so I can not pass a docker run command.

Ideally it would be great if I did not need to run the `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`. I'm not really sure why I can't set these to something static every time I start the machine.

So I am trying to set them using the bash command but Python just returns an empty string and then returns an error if I try to do `docker run my_container`.

Error:

```
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/docker/docker-py

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I looked into it but then I came across this: http://blog.bordage.pro/avoid-docker-py/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest running these two steps to start a machine in a bash script first. Then you can have that same bash script call your python script and access docker with `docker-py`

```
import docker
import os

docker_host = os.environ['DOCKER_HOST']
client = docker.Client(docker_host)
client.create(...)
...
```